# PowerShell: (Save files with the original name) Out-File -FilePath (keep the same name, without rename it)

Tags: powershell

just to understand the saving option on Powershell. The code below mix words from a particular file, into one folder, it save that file with a different name.

```
((Get-Content -Path C:\Folder1\file.txt -Raw ) -split "\s+" | 
    Sort-Object {Get-Random} ) -join ' ' |
        Out-File -FilePath C:\Folder1\NewFile.txt
```

Now, I modify a little bit the code. Because I want to select all text files, from the same folder, but save them with the same name. So I want to modify each files, but keeping the original name on save.

I believe I made something wrong. Can you help me, please?

```
((Get-Content -Path C:\Folder1\*.txt -Raw ) -split "\s+" | 
    Sort-Object {Get-Random} ) -join ' ' |
        Out-File -FilePath C:\Folder1\-W
```

Comment: You will have to use a loop iterating over all files.

Comment: I do not know what you mean. I'm a beginner in Powershell

Comment: [Foreach-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.2) ... please read the help completely including the examples to learn how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$Fllist=get-childitem "c:\folder" | ?{$_.name -ilike "*.txt"}

foreach($File in $Fllist) {
    ((Get-Content -Path "C:\Folder1\$($File.name)" -Raw -Encoding UTF8) -split "\s+" |
      Sort-Object {Get-Random} ) -join ' ' |
      Out-File -FilePath "c:\Folder1\$($File.name)"
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware of that requirement. Thanks for letting me know